# Sending with tcp/ip

Tags: java, client-server, tcp

I have client-server application and i need to send words from client to server and on server they must be separated(i will use them in DB), what is the best way to do it, send each word separately or may be divided line with all words on server?

Client:

```
//arraylist
ArrayList<String> Arsend = new ArrayList<String>();
send.add("dod");
send.add("sani");
send.add("fred");
//sending
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(Arsend);
```

Server:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
Object o = in.readObject();
System.out.println(o); //[dod, sani, fred]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
Object o = in.readObject();
System.out.println(o); //[dod, sani, fred]
```

Use:

```
//Cast in.readObject() to ArrayList<String>
ArrayList<String> receivedList = (ArrayList<String>)in.readObject();
//Loop through receivedList using for-each loop and print every String
for(String s : receivedList){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```